# fadeOut row and fadeIn as last row

Tags: jquery, fadein

I'm trying to fadeOut a row and fadeIn as the last row in the table, but I can't get the fadeIn to work.

Currently I have this:

```
function Test(control) {
            var row = $(control).parents('tr');

            row.find("td").fadeOut('slow', function () {
                var lastRow = $("#table1 tr:last");
                lastRow.after(row).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
```

Even if I leave off fadeIn lastRow.after(row) doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You want to fade out all the rows of the table, and then fade the **last** table row back into view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) returns `lastRow`, not the row you inserted after it like you want, so use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) like this:

```
function Test(control) {
  var row = $(control).closest('tr');
  row.fadeOut('slow', function () {
    row.insertAfter("#table1 tr:last").fadeIn('slow');
  });
}
```

Also note we're fading the `<tr>` we're fading back in, not the individual `<td>` elements (fading the parent back in doesn't help if the children are hidden).  Also look at [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)...it's much cheaper/more precise.

---

The above was meant to show the corrected version, you could also slim it down to:

```
function Test(control) {
  $(control).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $(this).insertAfter("#table1 tr:last").fadeIn('slow');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Do you know why IE8 would just insert it without fading in or out?  It works perfect in the other browsers.

Comment: @zLan - Fading table elements is tricky in IE since a `<tr>` isn't actually a displayed element, it *should* at least have the delay though, are you not seeing that?

Comment: Yeah there is the delay like it should be fading. Is there not an easy fix for this?

Comment: thanks!  had used chaning (eg. fadeout().insertafter().fadein() but effect ran after row move.  Your answer fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    $('tr').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).appendTo('table').fadeIn(500);
    });
```

[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/r2PCV/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
$(this).fadeIn('slow').insertAfter("#table1 tr:last")
```